# Issue in converting SQL query with ANY operator to Sequelize findAll function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, inner-join

I have three tables given as :
1. posts(postId(PK), postTitle, postDescription)
2. campaigns(campaignId(PK), platformId(FK), effectiveFrom, effectiveThrough, postArray: postId[])
   // Here postArray contains postIds of Integer type
3. platforms(platformId(PK), platformName)

and the query I'm running on PostgreSQL Client is:

```
select posts.*, platforms.*, campaigns.campaignId, campaigns.platformId, campaigns.postArray
from campaigns
INNER JOIN platforms
ON campaigns.platformId = platforms.platformId
INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.postId = ANY(campaigns.postArray);
```

which returns the following output:

```
postid  posttitle   postdescription platformid  platformname    campaignid  platformid  postarray
1       Post1       This is Post1       1       Facebook        1           1          {1,2,3}
2       Post2       This is Post2       1       Facebook        1           1          {1,2,3}
3       Post3       This is Post3       1       Facebook        1           1          {1,2,3}
2       Post2       This is Post2       1       Facebook        2           1          {2,4,5}
4       Post4       This is Post4       1       Facebook        2           1          {2,4,5}
5       Post5       This is Post5       1       Facebook        2           1          {2,4,5}
2       Post2       This is Post2       3       LinkedIn        3           3          {2,3,4,5}
...
```

Now I want the same output in Sequelize and not sure how to use 'Any' operator in findAll function.

This is my findAll code:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {
    Campaigns.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Platform,
                required: true
            },
            {
                model: Post,
                required: true,
                [Op.any]: ['"postArray"']
            }
        ],
        order:[
            ['"campaignId"', 'ASC']
        ]
    })
    .then(campaign=> {
        res.status(200).json(campaign.sort(function(c1, c2){return c1.campaignId - c2.campaignId}));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({msg: "error", details: err});
    });
};
```

& these are the relations:

```
  db.campaigns.hasMany(db.posts,{sourceKey: 'postId', foreignKey: 'postArray'});
  db.campaigns.hasOne(db.platforms,{sourceKey: 'platformId', foreignKey: 'platformId'});
```

I know I'm doing it wrong and it won't run. Kindly suggest me a solution and better approach to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize doesn't support relations via arrays. Creating JOINs by using include only supports relations defined in sequelize, and since one cannot define the relation in sequelize, it's not possible.